# How to say that "listen to the sound from the computer directly instead of using an earphone"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I don't know how to express myself when I want to say that I don't use my earphone when I listen to the music from my computer.

For example,

> Please do not _____, use earphone/headphone instead.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence or dialogue so that we can give you an accurate answer? Also, what is wrong with "I don't use my earphone[s] when I listen to the music from my computer"?

Comment: I just wonder if there is a shorter way in oral English for that...

Comment: The speaker... You use the speakers. Also, I don't think "earphone" is common... I hear "earbuds" for the little in-ear headphones.

Comment: ...Please do not listen to your computer's built-in speakers, use earphones instead.

Comment: @Catija, earphones is number two after headphones. earbuds is way way down. In words... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earpieces%2C+earphones%2C+earbuds%2C+headphones&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearpieces%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearphones%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cearbuds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheadphones%3B%2Cc0 In pictures... https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=earphones+images&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMlffR0p_TAhVJcBoKHS4CA7IQsAQIIQ&biw=1600&bih=829

Comment: @JavaLatte Ngram is not really the best resource for that sort of thing. Particularly since you're limiting the results to before 2000... Regardless, I didn't say that it's not a search term, I said that I don't think it's common... because, as a native speaker, I don't hear people use it at all.

Comment: @JavaLatte "*They are sold at times with foam pads for comfort. (The use of the term "earbuds", which has been around since at least 1984, did not hit its peak until after 2001, with the success of Apple's MP3 player.*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headphones#Earphones

Comment: @Catija, I'm not disputing the existence of the term earbuds, but earphones is the more widely used term by the people that I know: both natives and ESLs. Google gives 45 million hits for earphones and 24 million for earbuds. I don't think that many lay people know the difference betwee them, but here's a summary of the differences: https://www.lifewire.com/earphones-vs-earbuds-2640208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't listen to music "*with/from/using* your computer speakers".  Instead you use headphones.

Note that there is some overlap in the meaning of "headphones" and "earphones" which may vary from person to person.  *Technically* [these](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0362/2465/products/pm-3_01_400x.jpg?v=1484848825) are "headphones", and [these](http://www.wirerealm.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/what-are-earbuds-300x285.jpg) are called "earbuds" -- but I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You use the speakers.

> When I'm at home, I listen to music on my computer's speakers. When I'm at work, they've asked me to use my headphones instead so that I don't bother the people around me.

I don't know that "earphone" is a widely-used phrase. Generally people call them "earbuds" if they're in-ear headphones like these.

[image: Image of wired black earbuds]

But people will regularly still call these "headphones".

Comment: I am aware of the term earbud, but to me it sounds very.....Appley for want of a better term. It might be generational, but I would definitely call those earphones, with the type which cover the ears being headphones.